# Designing QTApplication with a web browser integrated?

Tags: qt4

Hi I am designing a QT application and have a form that should serve as a sort of web browser but should only allow navigation within the setUrl page I put in there.

My problem however is that I have tried following examples and noticed they are all using their web browsers as the main page (main.cpp) which I don't want to do.

here is the line of code I had intended to use to load the page to my form.

//ui->pageLoader->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
//ui->pageLoader->showMaximized();

but I always get error.

Comment: here is a code from an example I saw online.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look ath `QWebKit` examples, `QWebKit` includes many useful classes such as `QWebView`, `QWebPage`, etc.. which will allow you to integrate a fully functional web-browser into your application.

Please share all the non-functioning code.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    ui->webView->load(QUrl(ui->lineEdit->text()));
}                                                                                 
                                                                      and have the following error returned:
                                                                       :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.:-1:                                                                Simply adding the webView to my application results in an error.